# Insert data in neo4J from a formated file

Tags: java, xml, json, neo4j, insertion

I'm really new with neo4j. I have the java objects that I want them to be my nodes e.t.c. Is there any way to extract them into an xml,json,simpe txt and after that insert them into the graph database (from the extracted file).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do it, from ETL tools via CSV files to GraphML. Look at http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import and see if you find a good method that suits you. I would recommend Michaels CSV Batch Importer, https://github.com/jexp/batch-import